# Copy row contents that are true from specific columns from different worksheets into a particular worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy the row contents from 3 specific columns from different worksheets on my workbook, to a particular range in a particular worksheet. e.g in Sheet1 I have a range from B1 to E40 I want to copy the contents from Columns B to D that display “TRUE” in column E and then paste it to Worksheet named “Analysis”.

I want the macro to go in Sheet 2, Sheet 3 and Sheet 4 and do the same (look for TRUE in column E and copy the rows B to D that meet that criteria) and paste the values one below the other in worksheet “Analysis”.

I’m pretty new to VBA and I have found a code that I think will be helpful to start with but I need help. Could you please give me an idea? I enclose the code that I found so that you can give me your comments it might not be the one needed but at list it might be a base. Many thanks.

```
Sub MyCode()

Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'Start search in row 3
LSearchRow = 3

'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = 2

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

'If value in column BA = "Soccer", copy entire row to Sheet2
If Range("BA" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Soccer" Then

    'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
    Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Move counter to next row
    LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

    'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    End If

    LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

'Position on cell A3
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A3").Select

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for Sheet1. However you need to clarify where exactly you want to copy the values to on the "Analysis"-sheet.

```
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lR As Long, lastRow As Long, k As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

lastRow = 1

For k = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    If Sheets(k).Name <> "Analysis" Then
        Set ws = Sheets(k)
        lR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lR
            If ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = True Then
                lastRow = lastRow + 1
                For j = 2 To 4 '2 represents Columns(2) = B and 4 represents Columns(4) = D
                    If ws.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis").Cells(lastRow, j - 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, j)
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Next k
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried to insert the code but it seems that is not doing anything. I have also tried to insert the range in the "Analysis" worksheet but it still doesn't seem to work. Do you have any thoughts on that? Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sub Copy_Paste()


Dim i As Long, j As Long, lR As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet1
lR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lR
    For j = 2 To 4 '2 represents Columns(2) = B and 4 represents Columns(4) = D
        If ws.Cells(i, j).Value <> "" And ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = True Then
            lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis").Range("A1:C").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis").Range("A1:E").Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, j)
        End If
     Next j
Next i
End Sub

Comment: Please tell me in words: Where do you want to copy the values to? What column on the 'Analysis'-sheet? One column per `Sheet`?

Comment: I want to copy the contents of the columns B-D that are "True" form the other worksheets and then paste them anywhere into columns A-C in the "Analysis" worksheet. Many thanks

Comment: Please try edited answer. Please include VBA error messages if you have any further issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is almost perfect. The only thing is, that it is pasting the values from the different worksheets vertically on the columns based on where the worksheet tab is located. I needed it to paste horizontally on the rows in columns A-C and pasting the total number of cells that are true on the other sheets into the "Analysis" sheet as a list one on top of the other. Hope I expressed myself correctly many thanks in advance for all your help and patience.

Comment: I edited the code again. If column E shows true, then column B - C will be copied to the 'Analysis'-sheet. This goes for all values in the row. New values will be added in new row. If it still isn't the solution, please add a screenshot to your question.

Comment: Perfect my friend! That is exactly what I needed. If I want to paste it in starting in another column in the "Analysis" Worksheet what do I need specify? Many thanks :)

Comment: Cool, if it worked please accept my answer as the solution to your question.